# Retrieve posts from meta key

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

I'm trying to query the list of posts using the meta_key but the result I got back was an empty array.

To write the data, I used the following codes:

```
$post_id = 2;
$user_key = 'ldp_system_follows_user_1';
$user_data_new = array(
    'followed'    => 'nofollowed'
);

update_post_meta($post_id, $user_key, $user_data_new);
```

The above code persisted the following in db when executing `get_post_meta(post_id);`

```
{
  "ldp_system_follows_user_1": [
    "a:1:{s:8:\"followed\";s:8:\"followed\";}"
  ]
}
```

I wanted to retrieve all the post ids that matches the meta data I wrote but it returned an empty array.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_query'    => array(
                                array(
                                    'key'   => $user_key,
                                    'value' => $user_data_new,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                                ))
    );

    return  get_posts($args);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested by phatskat, here are the SQL statement when I changed `'value' => 'follow'` and `'value' => 'nofollow'` respectively. However, I'm still getting the empty array back:

```
//'value' => $user_data_new,
"query": {
    "post_type": "post",
    "post_status": "publish",
    "meta_query": [
      {
        "key": "ldp_system_follows_user_1",
        "value": {
          "followed": "nofollowed"
        },
        "compare": "LIKE"
      }
    ]
  },


"request": "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( \n  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ldp_system_follows_user_1' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%followed%' )\n) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10",

"request": "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( \n  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ldp_system_follows_user_1' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%nofollowed%' )\n) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10",
```

Comment: What is the value of `$user_data_new` in your query? According to the code from earlier, it's an array, but in the WP_Query docs: "value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array **only** when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'.." Emphasis mine. It looks like, if you're doing LIKE with an array, it won't work.

Comment: `$user_data_new = array('followed' => 'nofollowed');` is an array in my query. I changed `'compare' => 'IN'` but I'm getting an empty result.

Comment: Try debugging your query as I noted in my answer and see what the SQL statement looks like. If you can, change the value portion to "nofollowed" and the compare back to "LIKE" and see if that works.

Comment: Please see my question update.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `LIKE` comparison, try a string:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'   => $user_key,
            'value' => 'followed', // String here
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);

return  get_posts($args);
```

Also, you can use `WP_Query` to help you debug:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'   => $user_key,
            'value' => 'followed', // String here
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<xmp>';
print_r( $query->result ); 
die;
```

`$query->result` should contain the generated SQL, and will show you how WordPress is preparing your meta data.